# Difference between http webrequest and web client?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, system.net

To upload large data when I use http web request it gives me time out error, but when I use web client,it uploads without any problem.
I read on the internet that web client is nothing but abstraction of http webrequest. So, what is different happening when I am using web client.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Presumably a different timeout is set